# How can i concatenate using resource string with placeholders?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have a function that displays the username. It works fine but I am getting this warning and I was wondering how to solve it.

[image: The function and warning]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the string in the strings.xml, do not hardcode it in the code.
"Welcome, %s"

Then use it in the code:

```
getString(R.string.welcome_message).format(userProfile?.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your string like this     Welcome %1$s
And when you want to use it

```
context.getString(R.string.welcome,userProfile?.username)
```